# latexindent.pl: indent brace blocks similar to C-style languages

Tags: latexindent

Suppose I have the following code listing:

```latex
font/lm/.code={
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\RequirePackage[rm={lining=true}]{cfr-lm}
\RequirePackage{amsfonts, amssymb}
% Define tabular-lining figures and oldstyle windows
\providerobustcmd{\tablining}{\tlstyle}
\providerobustcmd{\propold}{\postyle}
% Define bold small caps for AC and other header labels
\providerobustcmd{\labelstyle}[#1]{}
% Define title style
\providerobustcmd{}[]{}
\RequirePackage{inconsolata}
},
```

Running `latexindent.pl` on this file with the default options as specified in `defaultSettings.yaml` gives this result:

```latex
font/lm/.code={
        \RequirePackage{fix-cm}
        \RequirePackage[rm={lining=true}]{cfr-lm}
        \RequirePackage{amsfonts, amssymb}
        % Define tabular-lining figures and oldstyle windows
        \providerobustcmd{\tablining}{\tlstyle}
        \providerobustcmd{\propold}{\postyle}
        % Define bold small caps for AC and other header labels
        \providerobustcmd{\labelstyle}[#1]{}
        % Define title style
        \providerobustcmd{}[]{}
        \RequirePackage{inconsolata}
    },
```

Ideally, I'd like the indent of the closing brace `}` to be on the **same level** as the `font/lm/...` line, and the argument within the braces, i.e. the various `\RequirePackage`s and the `providerobustcmd{}...` to be indented by four spaces, similar to the function bodies of C-style languages:

```
int main() {
    // code
}
```

Of course, I'd like to extend this to optional arguments as well—this would be particularly useful when typesetting `tikzpicture`/`pgfplots` environments, where there are easily tens of arguments within the square brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fiddling around with different permutations of the settings in `defaultSettings.yaml`, I arrived at the following code segment that works precisely as intended: braces not indented, body code indented as specified (intended-indented wordplay not intended).

```yaml
# set noAdditionalIndent globally for codeblocks
noAdditionalIndentGlobal:
    environments: 0
    commands: 1
    optionalArguments: 0
    mandatoryArguments: 0
    ifElseFi: 0
    items: 0
    keyEqualsValuesBracesBrackets: 1
    namedGroupingBracesBrackets: 1
    UnNamedGroupingBracesBrackets: 1
    specialBeginEnd: 0
    afterHeading: 0
    filecontents: 0
```

To be very honest, I am not quite sure *why* this works, but it does. I shall consult the manual and post an update when I can.

Comment: I'm glad you found the answer. For your example the necessary part of your YAML file is `keyEqualsValuesBracesBrackets: 1`. See https://latexindentpl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sec-default-user-local.html#noadditionalindent-and-indentrules and also https://latexindentpl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sec-default-user-local.html#keyequalsvaluesbracesbrackets for reference.

Comment: By the way, if the documentation can be clearer on this issue, please do feel free to raise an issue or submit a pull request to (the develop branch) https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl